# Can we invalidate the old access token after logout on MFP?

Tags: java, jwt, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mfp

I am using IBM Mobilefirst platform 8.0 at the moment.
Currently, I am facing a problem:

On my MFP, I have 1 security check to protect 1 adapter.
The flow is that:

1. login with the security check
2. can obtain access token (I call it TOKEN_1)
3. can request resource from adapter
4. logout
5. This step, I use the TOKEN_1 to request the resource from adapter and it returns 401 unauthorized (it's correct here)
6. login with the security check again
7. can obtain a new access token now (I call it TOKEN_2)

At this time, I can use both TOKEN_1 and TOKEN_2 to request the resource from the adapter and I think that it's not a good thing (just for my case and from my point of view)

I would think that the TOKEN_1 should not be valid anymore but only the TOKEN_2.

So, my question is that there is any way to invalidate forever an access token after we logout with MFP?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Logout clears the token locally. What API do you use to logout? Also, is this specific to Android or iOS ? Cordova or native?

Comment: we're using WL.logout() function and behind the scene, it call the "/preauth/v1/logout" endpoint on MFP

Comment: WLAuthorizationManager.logout(securitycheck)  ?  This clears the token in the SDK. What version of SDK are you using and native or Cordova? Android/iOS?

Comment: We are using Cordova. But we can capture the OLD and NEW access token when WL make request to the adapter on MFP and the point that I mentioning is that currently, we can use both OLD and NEW access token to call adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually clear out the access tokens in the mobile device using the API [clearAccessToken](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLAuthorizationManager.html#clearAccessToken).

You can invoke it before or after your logout call. This is to ensure all token related data held in-memory is cleared. This does not clear any token data you have recorded within in your code and stored.

Once you have logged out with WLAuthorizationManager.logout(securitycheck) , the next time you request a protected resource, MFP client SDK always obtains a new token.

Comment: hi Vivin K, thank you for your reply.
I know that API. But I am wondering about the access token. After we logout and login again, the old access token should not be valid anymore, right? That is the main point.

Comment: WLAuthorizationManager.logout(securitycheck)  ?  This clears the token in the SDK. What version of SDK are you using and native or Cordova? Android/iOS?

Comment: We are using Cordova. But we can capture the OLD and NEW access token when WL make request to the adapter on MFP and the point that I mentioning is that currently, we can use both OLD and NEW access token to call adapter.

Comment: Will check this.